# Why was this question deleted and not closed?

Tags: discussion, support, closing, deletion, specific-flag

I flagged [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089708/spinner-probability-place-your-own-numbers) question as unclear what you're asking (the problem was later fixed) and my flag was moments ago marked as helpful, however, instead of the post being closed as unclear what you're asking, the question was deleted.

Did the user delete it? If so, why was my flag marked helpful?

Comment: Note that although the Question did receive downvotes, it also got two good Answers.  In a sense the Community validated the OP's perception that their nephew's assigned problem was vague, while helping to provide a sensible interpretation (two numbers are to be placed on the spinner).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system deleted the post because that user was removed. I didn't look to see why the user was removed --- he or she might have requested deletion, or perhaps not.

When the post was deleted, your flag was marked as helpful.

Comment: FWIW, the user deleted their own account (which is possible so long as the account never voted, and posted at most once, [source](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)). It should be added that the question was deleted along with the account because it had a negative score; non-negative-scored posts are not deleted when the associated account is deleted.